# Paper.JS raster artefacts

Tags: animation, rotation, raster, paperjs

there is a task to spread some raster cubes (PNG, with transparent background) along
the canvas based on Paper.JS platform.

I did it, however, there is a bug – canvas is bigger than browser window and when you are scrolling it to the right, animated cubes go glitchy, see attached screenshot. It seems that 
the renderer doesn't clear previous frames. The same bug occurs in all browsers.

Is anyone knows how to overcome it? When I am trying to resize window and call onResize, everything becomes good unless I am not trying to scroll it again.

[artefact image](http://ge.tt/8BXHQz91/v/0)

Comment: Could you post your code or a link to an example?

Comment: http://area51.vkuchinov.co.uk/artefact01/

Actually, control script is here
http://www.area51.vkuchinov.co.uk/artefact01/js/cubes2D.js

Answer (score 1):

Try using symbols instead of recreating the same rasters over and over:

In you 'building cubes' setup:

```
sprites[s] = new Symbol(new Raster(urls[s]));
```

and in hive():

```
var tmpRaster = sprites[selector].place();
```

Also, I believe paper.js tries to not animate off-screen elements to save on processing time. Instead of having the canvas be larger than the viewport, you may be better off using `view.scrollBy(point)`